# Como criar um header do tipo date mas na forma de ISO 8601

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, header

Eu estou a criar uma comunicação com uma web api e eu precisava de criar um *header* do tipo date mas formatado a *ISO 8601*. O que eu pretendo é obter o seguinte output :

> Date: 2017-09-13T08:21:08Z

O meu código é o seguinte:

```
var tempo = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("test.com");
```

O que eu já tentei :

```
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Date", tempo);
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add($"Date: {DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")}");
httpWebRequest.Headers["Date"] = tempo;
```

Com estes códigos obtive o seguinte erro :

> System.ArgumentException: 'O cabeçalho 'Date' tem de ser modificado
>   com a propriedade ou o método adequado.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O *header* deve ser alterado da seguinte forma:

```
httpWebRequest.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Veja um exemplo [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cwbUC1).

Answer (score 0):

Eu já encontrei uma maneira de resolver este problema por isso vou deixar a minha resposta para poder ajudar alguém que tenha a mesma duvida que eu mas obrigado a quem ajudou.
A resposta :

```
MethodInfo priMethod = httpWebRequest.Headers.GetType().GetMethod("AddWithoutValidate", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
priMethod.Invoke(httpWebRequest.Headers, new[] { "Date", tempo });
```

O output que obtenho é este :

> Date: 2017-09-13T08:21:08Z

Comment: A forma que demonstrou não efectua o output que eu pretendo mas esta solução que eu encontrei  efectua o output que eu pretendia, mas muito obrigado pela sua ajuda